# What are "(TNS V1-V3)" connections in database

Tags: oracle, tns

I see there are many connections are lying in our database (gv$session) module as "(TNS V1-V3)" and program also same as "(TNS V1-V3)". These are connections are inactive status and that too not balanced across both db nodes. We have database two node RAC setup (11.0.2.3) (oracle super cluster).

Due to high connections in one of nodes, all application services are getting connected to specific db node. example node-2. during high load CPU usage going up. How can i reduce or remove these connections.
Any suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Those are any connections that occur through the TNS listener.  If they are inactive, they are not really causing a problem unless the number of total sessions hits the database parameter `sessions` in which case that node will stop accepting new connections.  I would check to see if whatever application you are using is using connection pooling, and if the connection pool is properly configured to disconnect its session after a certain amount of idle time.  Please add a tag for your Oracle version, like `oracle12c`.  You can also look at your TNS listener log files; do a

```
 lsnrctl show log_directory
```

to display where your listener log file is.

Also try the following query to see if `sessions` limit for the instances is close to the limit:

```
select a.inst_id, a.value,
        count(b.sid) as sessions_used,
        to_number(a.value) - count(b.sid) as avail_sessions
from gv$parameter a, gv$session b
where a.name='sessions' and a.inst_id=b.inst_id
group by a.inst_id, a.value
```

My results on a non-RAC database:

```
   INST_ID VALUE  SESSIONS_USED AVAIL_SESSIONS
---------- ------ ------------- --------------
         1 772               74            698
```